# PostgreSQL query where column is represented as a string

Tags: string, postgresql, retool

I'm using Retool, and trying to run a query where the column value comes from a drop-down list. The value output is a string, so my query looks like this:

```
select * from accounts where {{dropDownList.value}} ilike {{'%' + account_search_textInput.value + '%'}}
```

When the query runs, it is as follows:

```
select * from accounts where "first_name" ilike '%Adam%';
```

The double quotes around the column name `first_name` seem to be causing an issue but I don't think I can remove them. Is there any other way to successfully run the query where `first_name` can represent the column name rather than a string value?

Comment: `"first_name"` is just a quoted identifier and should not cause an issue per [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). To your question add the complete error message you get that makes you think this is an issue.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver there's no error per se, but when I query with the quotes around "first_name" the query results in 0 returned rows, whereas first_name without quotes returns 1 record. (The correct query should return 1 record)

Comment: If you can't remove the quotes how are you doing the query without them?